# Unable to understand a error from gradle build -Xlint:unchecked

Tags: gradle

I got this error while building hibernate using gradle

```
:hibernate-entitymanager:compileTestJava
/home/jsiddharth/workspace/hibernate-orm-master/hibernate-entitymanager/src/test/java/org/hibernate/jpa/test/criteria/paths/SingularAttributeJoinTest.java:128: error: <anonymous org.hibernate.jpa.test.criteria.paths.SingularAttributeJoinTest$2> is not abstract and does not override abstract method integrate(MetadataImplementor,SessionFactoryImplementor,SessionFactoryServiceRegistry) in Integrator
        return new Integrator() {
                                ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
:hibernate-entitymanager:compileTestJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I assumed that I need to run gradle with the -Xlint options, but turns out, I am doing it wrong. I got this error when I ran

> ./gradlew eclipse  -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked Maven settings.xml file did not exist : /home/jsiddharth/.m2/settings.xml

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :eclipse from command line. Unknown command-line option '-X'.
> Unknown command-line option '-X'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.185 secs
```

How do I run my build to ignore the errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to you question, the `-Xlint` is a Java compiler option and has nothing to do with Gradle. You can specify these options via `GRADLE_OPTS` which is how Gradle passes arguments to the JVM.

Specifically: `GRADLE_OPTS="-Xlint:deprecation"`

Anyway this is not your trouble. Have a look at the error:

> SingularAttributeJoinTest$2> is not abstract and does not override abstract method integrate(MetadataImplementor,SessionFactoryImplementor,SessionFactoryServiceRegistry) in Integrator
>           return new Integrator() {

You have an anonymous class inside `SingularAttributeJoinTest` which is declared to implement `Integrator` but fails to implement method `integrate` and is not declared abstract. This kind of error can't be suppressed by a `-Xlint` option of course.

Comment: **Partly wrong;** JVM says "`Unrecognized option: -Xlint:unchecked`" and/or "`Unrecognized option: -Xlint:deprecation`", because that is an option for Compiler only, never JVM. Test yourself like```: 
                                                        GRADLE_OPTS="-Xlint:deprecation" ./gradlew assembleDebug```